# How do I recursively use newStdGen in Haskell? (to get different random results on each iteration)

Tags: haskell, recursion, random

I use System.Random and System.Random.Shuffle to shuffle the order of characters in a string, I shuffle it using:

```
shuffle' string (length string) g
```

g being a getStdGen.

Now the problem is that the shuffle can result in an order that's identical to the original order, resulting in a string that isn't really shuffled, so when this happens I want to just shuffle it recursively until it hits a a shuffled string that's not the original string (which should usually happen on the first or second try), but this means I need to create a new random number generator on each recursion so it wont just shuffle it exactly the same way every time.

But how do I do that? Defining a

```
newg = newStdGen
```

in "where", and using it results in:

```
Jumble.hs:20:14:
    Could not deduce (RandomGen (IO StdGen))
      arising from a use of shuffle'
    from the context (Eq a)
      bound by the inferred type of
               shuffleString :: Eq a => IO StdGen -> [a] -> [a]
      at Jumble.hs:(15,1)-(22,18)
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (RandomGen (IO StdGen))
    In the expression: shuffle' string (length string) g
    In an equation for `shuffled':
        shuffled = shuffle' string (length string) g
    In an equation for `shuffleString':
        shuffleString g string
          = if shuffled == original then
                shuffleString newg shuffled
            else
                shuffled
          where
              shuffled = shuffle' string (length string) g
              original = string
              newg = newStdGen

Jumble.hs:38:30:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO StdGen' with actual type `StdGen'
    In the first argument of `jumble', namely `g'
    In the first argument of `map', namely `(jumble g)'
    In the expression: (map (jumble g) word_list)
```

I'm very new to Haskell and functional programming in general and have only learned the basics, one thing that might be relevant which I don't know yet is the difference between "x = value", "x <- value", and "let x = value".

Complete code:

```
import System.Random
import System.Random.Shuffle

middle :: [Char] -> [Char]
middle word
  | length word >= 4 = (init (tail word))
  | otherwise = word

shuffleString g string =
  if shuffled == original
    then shuffleString g shuffled
    else shuffled
  where
  shuffled = shuffle' string (length string) g
  original = string

jumble g word
  | length word >= 4 = h ++ m ++ l
  | otherwise = word
  where
  h = [(head word)]
  m = (shuffleString g (middle word))
  l = [(last word)]

main = do
  g <- getStdGen
  putStrLn "Hello, what would you like to jumble?"
  text <- getLine
  -- let text = "Example text"
  let word_list = words text
  let jumbled = (map (jumble g) word_list)
  let output = unwords jumbled
  putStrLn output
```

Comment: I've expanded my answer to possibly help shed some light on Haskell's syntax for assigning values to names (note that I'm doing my best to avoid using the term "variable", since Haskell doesn't really have those).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple, you know that `g` has type `StdGen`, which is an instance of the `RandomGen` typeclass.  The `RandomGen` typeclass has the functions `next :: g -> (Int, g)`, `genRange :: g -> (Int, Int)`, and `split :: g -> (g, g)`.  Two of these functions return a new random generator, namely `next` and `split`.  For your purposes, you can use either quite easily to get a new generator, but I would just recommend using `next` for simplicity.  You could rewrite your `shuffleString` function to something like

```
shuffleString :: RandomGen g => g -> String -> String
shuffleString g string =
    if shuffled == original
        then shuffleString (snd $ next g) shuffled
        else shuffled
    where
        shuffled = shuffle' string (length string) g
        original = string
```

---

**End of answer to this question**

---

> One thing that might be relevant which I don't know yet is the difference between "x = value", "x <- value", and "let x = value".

These three different forms of assignment are used in different contexts.  At the top level of your code, you can define functions and values using the simple `x = value` syntax.  These statements are not being "executed" inside any context other than the current module, and most people would find it pedantic to have to write

```
module Main where

let main :: IO ()
    main = do
        putStrLn "Hello, World"
        putStrLn "Exiting now"
```

since there isn't any ambiguity at this level.  It also helps to delimit this context since it is only at the top level that you can declare data types, type aliases, and type classes, these can not be declared inside functions.

The second form, `let x = value`, actually comes in two variants, the `let x = value in <expr>` inside pure functions, and simply `let x = value` inside monadic functions (do notation).  For example:

```
myFunc :: Int -> Int
myFunc x =
    let y = x + 2
        z = y * y
    in z * z
```

Lets you store intermediate results, so you get a faster execution than

```
myFuncBad :: Int -> Int
myFuncBad x = (x + 2) * (x + 2) * (x + 2) * (x + 2)
```

But the former is also equivalent to

```
myFunc :: Int -> Int
myFunc x = z * z
    where
        y = x + 2
        z = y * y
```

There are subtle difference between `let ... in ...` and `where ...`, but you don't need to worry about it at this point, other than the following is only possible using `let ... in ...`, not `where ...`:

```
myFunc x = (\y -> let z = y * y in z * z) (x + 2)
```

The `let ...` syntax (without the `in ...`) is used only in monadic do notation to perform much the same purpose, but usually using values bound inside it:

```
something :: IO Int
something = do
    putStr "Enter an int: "
    x <- getLine
    let y = myFunc (read x)
    return (y * y)
```

This simply allows `y` to be available to all proceeding statements in the function, and the `in ...` part is not needed because it's not ambiguous at this point.

The final form of `x <- value` is used especially in monadic do notation, and is specifically for extracting a value out of its monadic context.  That may sound complicated, so here's a simple example.  Take the function `getLine`.  It has the type `IO String`, meaning it performs an `IO` action that returns a `String`.  The types `IO String` and `String` *are not the same*, you can't call `length getLine`, because `length` doesn't work for `IO String`, but it does for `String`.  However, we frequently want that `String` value inside the `IO` context, without having to worry about it being wrapped in the `IO` monad.  This is what the `<-` is for.  In this function

```
main = do
    line <- getLine
    print (length line)
```

`getLine` still has the type `IO String`, but `line` now has the type `String`, and can be fed into functions that expect a `String`.  Whenever you see `x <- something`, the `something` is a monadic context, and `x` is the value being extracted from that context.

So why does Haskell have so many different ways of defining values?  It all comes down to its type system, which tries really hard to ensure that you can't accidentally launch the missiles, or corrupt a file system, or do something you didn't really intend to do.  It also helps to visually separate what is an action, and what is a computation in source code, so that at a glance you can tell if an action is being performed or not.  It does take a while to get used to, and there are probably valid arguments that it could be simplified, but changing anything would also break backwards compatibility.

And that concludes today's episode of **Way Too Much Information<sup>(tm)</sup>**

(Note: To other readers, if I've said something incorrect or potentially misleading, please feel free to edit or leave a comment pointing out the mistake.  I don't pretend to be perfect in my descriptions of Haskell syntax.)

Comment: I should point out that although `next` will probably work, it's really `split` that's intended for this kind of use. (And you would then pass one of the new generators to `shuffle'` and the other to the recursion.) Although since there is barely any quality guarantee on `split` anyhow (in fact I vaguely recall one of the two generators returned *is* the `next` one), perhaps I shouldn't worry.

Comment: OK my vague recall is wrong or the code has changed, although it does use `next` as part of the very ad-hoc algorithm.